# Unable to check null value for the object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, properties

This is my class :

```
Public Class AddressForm

    Private Street As String

    Property Street_() As String
        Get
            Return Street
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                Street = ""
            Else
                Street = value
            End If

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

it is my object for above class BussinessAddressDialog

If Not BussinessAddressDialog.Street_ = String.Empty (here application crashes for empty value) 
 after this line i am inserting values in data base

Thnx for your help

Comment: Are you saying that `BussinessAddressDialog` is `Nothing`? Please post the line of code that causes the exception, and the actual exception message.

Comment: i am not getting exception application is crashed after this code     If Not BussinessAddressDialog.Street_ = String.Empty  if bussinessaddressdialog.street is empty

Comment: an application "crashes" BECAUSE there is an (unhandled) exception. Stating that you dont get one, therefore seems a bit unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ShortCircuit` technique:

```
If BussinessAddressDialog IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
   BussinessAddressDialog.Street_ = String.Empty Then
    ' Do you work here
End If
```

Probably `BussinessAddressDialog` is not initialized has set to `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Street` field is not going to be initialised before you're using it, you could put the same sort of logic in you're using for your `Set`, also you'll want to test for `value` being `Nothing` in your setter rather than it being something:

```
Public Class AddressForm

    Private Street As String

    Property Street_() As String
        Get
            If Street Is Nothing then
                Return String.Empty
            Else
                Return Street
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Street = ""
            Else
                Street = value
            End If

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Can you post the lines of code that are giving you the problem and the exact error message?